# How to replace " with "" in string builder using java

Tags: java

String ex="testing "is" always good";

I Need output as : testing is "" is "" always good

Comment: Check how to escape characters in strings. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Comment: This looks like a string, not a string builder.

Comment: Also, do you want to replace just the quotes, or like in your example, duplicate the "is" as well?

Comment: I have just given an example for understanding. i m using StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple follow the code,

```
 String str ="testing \"is\" always good";
 str.replaceAll("\"is\"", "is \"\" is \"\"");
```

Comment: No need to use `replaceAll` when searching for something which is a plain string and not a regular expression. The method `replace` does that and replaces *all* occurrences.

Comment: I need to use StringBuffer , and there is no replaceAll in string builder .